# Check if dynamic attribute value exist inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I've got this iframe that updates the value of the "data-active-video" attribute every time the users click next on slideshow..I'm trying to check whether "data-active-video" has a value of 4 and if it does change the "src" value..See code below thx

```
<div class="video-frame">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="EZF4iS-XEQ8" frameborder="0" id="active_video_player" allowfullscreen="" data-active-video="4"></iframe>
</div>
```

and JS:

```
$('.video-frame').find('iframe').each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('data-active-video', '4')) {
        // alert('yesssss');
        $(this).attr('src', 'http://www.somelink.com');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**[`attr('data-active-video', '4')`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** will set the attribute value to 4, to get data attribute value you need to use **[`attr('data-active-video')`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** or **[`data('active-video')`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)**

```
$('.video-frame iframe').each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('data-active-video') == '4') {
        // alert('yesssss');
        $(this).attr('src', 'http://www.somelink.com');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could also try like this. Since it seems that you are using jQuery. You could make use of the data attribute. Either ways it's the same as the answer above me.

```
$('.video-frame').find('iframe').each(function () {
if ($(this).data('active-video') == '4') {
    // alert('yesssss');
    $(this).attr('src', 'http://www.somelink.com');
}
```

});